# Django ORM multiple table join with AbstractUser

Tags: django, join, django-models, orm, abstractuser

I googled but got confused in multiple table join (with 1:1, 1:n, and n:m relations). My models looks like this:

> ```
> class User(AbstractUser):
>     is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
>     is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
>
> class Event(models.Model):
>     owner_events = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='events')
>     name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
>    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
>
>     def get_absolute_url(self): # defekt
>         return reverse('event_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
>         return self.name
>
>     def get_event(self):
>         name = escape(self.name)
>         date =  escape(self.date)
>         return "Name: " + str(name) + " Datum: " + str(date)
>
> class Teacher(models.Model):
>     user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
>     interests = models.ManyToManyField(Subject, related_name='interested_teachers') 
>     matches = models.ManyToManyField(Match, related_name="teacher_matches")
>
>     def __str__(self):
>         return self.user.username
>
>     def get_events(self):
>         return "Name: " + str(self.events.name) + "Date: "
>
>     def get_events_adr(self):
>         return self.events
>
>     def get_interests(self):
>         return "Interests: " + str(self.interests.name)
> ```

Here this is how the tables look like in the db:

[Classroom_Event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKaew.png)

[Classroom_Teacher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7jVS.png)

[Classroom_User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iw8EP.png)

In views I want to have events (event_id, name, date) and teachers information (user_id, name) displayed. In SQL it would be something like this:

> ```
> select classroom_event.id, classroom_event.name, classroom_event.date,
> classroom_user.id, classroom_user.username from classroom_event
>
> left join classroom_user on
> classroom_event.owner_events_id = classroom_user.id
>
> left join classroom_teacher on 
> classroom_user.id = classroom_teacher.user_id
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no need to to create abstract user.
just define two model for student and teacher and give theme one_to_one key to default User model, also no need for is student/teacher field too!.
just for enabling a better reverse call from User model to this two models, give a related_name in foreign key field, or there will be default "teacher_set" reverse.

```
for teacher in Teacher.objects.all():
    print(teacher.user.username)
```

or in reverse:

```
for user in User.objects.all():
   if user.teacher:
        print(user.teacher.username)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The abstract user was designed due to:
• Sharing common resources (e.g. login, logout, pw reset, pw change) across all accounts – I don’t want them to be spread across multiple tables.
• Customization of User model without relying on OneToOne models.

Therefore, I would like to leave the models as are. Is there still an ORM solution? Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. How would the JOIN with the "Event"-table look like then? Many thanks.